# How to check if SSRS Textbox text equals "0"

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to know if there is a way to created some kind of a function is SSRS that checks the value of a given textbox. If the value == "0", then, change it's text to "" (empty).

The idea here is to hide the content if the value is 0. The value comes from the database query results.

I would need a generic function because I have to apply this to a lot of textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

If these textboxes are going to have numbers in them, you can change the number formatting to not show the zeros. There's an option on the Text Box Properties/Format/Number for "Show zero as" and you can choose a blank.  You could then copy that format to your other textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to know if there is a way to created some kind of a function is SSRS that checks the value of a given textbox. If the value == "0", then, change it's text to "" (empty)."

You can use the **ReportItems** collection to access the textbox.

It is used in the same way as the Fields collection:

```
  =ReportItems!TextboxName.Value
```

So in your case the expression would be:

```
  =IIF(ReportItems!TextboxName.Value = 0, "",ReportItems!TextboxName.Value)
```